# Landscape application only one controller in Portrait - Swift 3

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3, orientation, landscape-portrait

In App Delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape.rawValue)
}
```

In my View Controller(MainViewController) I have added

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    supportedInterfaceOrientations()
    preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

private func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
}

private func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

private func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {

    // Only allow Portrait
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
}
```

This is the only controller in the application that I want to work in portrait mode. except this everything in Landscape mode.

But I've tried numerous things still unable to understand why is it not working.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for being noob in swift.

Answer (score 1):

**write this code in appdelegate**

```
var shouldRotate = false
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if shouldRotate {
        return .landscape
    }
    else {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

**set this code to your view controller in viewDidload()**

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.shouldRotate = true // or false to disable rotation
    //you can manage only changing true or false
```

**hope its helps you**

Comment: Hey @seggy No its not working. It did change the layout for keyboard to portrait. But the view controller is still landscape.

Comment: dude its working properly on my project. i think are you something wrong.

Comment: Hey @seggy It works when I rotate the device and do not force change the orientation. And I want the controller to force change the orientation

Comment: you can do it change .landscape to .all